# How can I distinguish between System and Third Party Credential Providers in Windows?

Tags: windows, credentials

I have a PowerShell script that fetches all installed Credential Providers from the Registry. I'm only interested in the Third Party Credential Providers.

Is there a reliable and automatable way to distinguish between System and Third Party Credential Providers?

Comment: This is really not related to PowerShell at all. I am not sure what you are asking for here. Windows and any Window's app will use the Windows API/DLL/SDK for all IDAM stack. That is a Windows requirement for being a certified for Windows app. That being said, you can of course install 3rdP IDAM, but PowerShell would not know anything about them. Each IDAM installer would list itself in the normal Add/Remove programs, in normal cases, but there are those that do not. You need to know what you are looking for by name when it comes to that.

Comment: For me it is required, that the automated solution integrates with a existing PowerShell script. But yes @postanote, you are right. The question itself has nothing to do with PowerShell. I removed the Tag accordingly.  

Nonetheless Windows lists all installed CPs in a Registry Entry. The Problem is, that it only lists an unique ID and a name for every CP. But there is no way to tell what ist a 3rdP CP und what is a system CP ust based on these 2 attributes. Is there a List of system CPs somewhere, maybe? that would already solve the Problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

There is a default set, and you can make a 3rdP determination by getting that list from the registry on a pristine system for the target OS you are after, and of course anything not in the default hive list is 3rdP or custom in-house developed one when you do a compare.

Of course you use the normal registry cmdlets to get the list ...

```
$RegKeyAuth = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication'
$RegKeyCredentialProviders = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\Credential Providers'

Get-ChildItem -Path $RegKeyAuth | 
Format-Table -AutoSize

Get-ItemProperty -Path $RegKeyCredentialProviders


Get-ChildItem -Path $RegKeyCredentialProviders | 
Format-Table -AutoSize
```

... or manually export from a system for the compare and parse as needed.